# Why does this relative link work like an absolute link?

Tags: html, browser, hyperlink, web-crawler

In this page http://www.english-attack.com/video-boosters, a link is included, just under the big image at the top:

```
<a href="videobooster/promised-land/do-you-have-what-it-takes#comments">3 comments</a>
```

There isn't a `base` elements on the page, and JavaScript is disabled.

To which one of these should *3 comments* point to:

1. http://www.english-attack.com/video-boosters/videobooster/promised-land/do-you-have-what-it-takes#comments
2. http://www.english-attack.com/videobooster/promised-land/do-you-have-what-it-takes#comments
3. http://www.english-attack.com/video-boostersvideobooster/promised-land/do-you-have-what-it-takes#comments

I would immediately say option *"1".* Which would mean I have to fix the links, because I want *"2"* to happen here. But, Chrome and Firefox will gladly open option *"2"* instead. However, the Google and Bing bots will follow link *"1"*.

What is wrong here?

Comment: There's no guarantee what different browsers implement, but the standards doc for how relative URLs should behave is at: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt

Answer (score 1):

The page containing the links has no `/` on the end.

The links are relative to `http://www.english-attack.com/video-boosters` not `http://www.english-attack.com/video-boosters/`

Everything after the last `/` is dropped so `http://www.english-attack.com/videobooster/promised-land/do-you-have-what-it-takes#comments` is correct.

See [the specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt):

> Step 6: The last segment of the base URL's path (anything
>              following the rightmost slash "/", or the entire path if no
>              slash is present) is removed and the embedded URL's path is
>              appended in its place.

Comment: OK, it now figures, this is how I used to link to "index.html" from "about.html" in the `90s :-)   But that would mean the bots are having issues.

Comment: Quentin, this makes sense, but you are saying on your other comment that <q>The browsers and search engines are resolving the URL correctly according to the specification</q>. Why the difference between the browser and bot implementation? Isn't the bot wrong to follow up on those paths?

Comment: @GabrielR. — Err. There isn't a difference. You said they both used option 2.

Comment: Argh, I made a stupid mistake, now corrected to say «However, the Google and Bing bots will follow link "1".»

Comment: That's a bug in the bots. Are you sure they really are Google and Bing and not spambots pretending to be Google and Bing?

Comment: Yes, I checked at least for Bing with their special form on the Bing Webmaster tools. I am also seeing these links in Google Analytics, so some end-users or desktop based bots also follow these, somehow.

Comment: After some more digging, I discovered that this was a plain bug in our code. I was blaming the bots, but it was us humans, again.

Comment: I've asked the mods to delete this. #shame